# Extract IPs from Pcap Which are Matching the String

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep, tcpdump

How can I extract IPs from a PCAP file whose packet has any of these hex strings.

```
--hex-string '|AF0DFT5F14|'
--hex-string '|AF0DFT5F25|'
--hex-string '|AF0DFT5F45|'
```

I just need the list of IPs.

I tried to search a lot on web but couldn't get any specific about this. I found out to extract all the IPs from a pcap file using the below command

```
( tcpdump -n -r m.pcap  | grep IP | cut -f 3 "-d " | cut -f1-4 -d.; tcpdump -n -r m.pcap  | grep IP | cut -f 5 "-d " | cut -f1-4 -d. ) | sort -u
```

Grep, awk, anything can do

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of output from the `tcpdump -n -r m.pcap` call (eg, 10-20 lines; with some lines containing the strings you're looking for); also update the question with the expected output (for said `tcpdump` sample output)

Comment: @markp-fuso sure :)

Comment: Am3Y there's not much we can do to help you without the example @markp-fuso asked for and the longer you wait to provide it the better chance your question's just going to get downvoted and closed for not having it. You're currently just 1 vote away from it being closed (I haven't voted to close it yet).

Comment: `tcpdump -txn` prints header (with IPs) and data in hex (unfortunately for you formatted) Use `sed` or `awk` to reformat, so you can simply `grep` then. OR check `tshark` https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html Maybe more suitable tool for this. Comes with wireshark, has similar filters

Comment: Parsing tcpdump pcap data with TXR Lisp: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131117/is-it-possible-to-view-unicode-text-in-tcpdump-capture-output